# Find the equation for the line tangent to the function $ f(x) = 2{\sqrt x}$ at $ x=25$

Tags: calculus

Find the equation for the line tangent to the function $f(x) = 2{\sqrt x}$ at $x=25$
Find the slope in two ways:

(i) by using the limit definition of the derivative,

(ii) and using derivative shortcut formulas.

I think was able to find that $p_1= (25,10)$ and bring to use derivative definition, but when I multiply by a "disguised $1$" ,$\frac{2{\sqrt {25+h}}-10}{2{\sqrt {25+h}}-10}$ I'm lost

Comment: calculate this limit 

$$ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{2 \sqrt{x+h}- 2\sqrt x}{h}$$
then put $x=25$. That gives you slope.

Comment: [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/306553) references to help you typeset maths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{2\sqrt{25+h} - 10}{h} &= \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{2\sqrt{25+h} - 10}{h} \cdot \frac{2\sqrt{25+h}+10}{2\sqrt{25+h}+10} \\
&=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{(2\sqrt{25+h})^2-10^2}{h(\sqrt{25+h}+10)}\\
&=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{4(25+h)-100}{h(\sqrt{25+h}+10)}\\\end{align}

Can you finish this?